# How to Search information within 2 or more websites

Tags: search, search-engine

I know that it is possible to search for information on a particular site by using the `site` key via Google and etc.

For example:

```
Name Lastname site:facebook.com
```

But how does a query look like, if I want to search info within 2 or more websites ?

Unfortunately this method wasn't return any results:

```
Name Lastname site:snapchat.com site:facebook.com
```

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about using Google search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pipe operator is what you're looking for ;D

```
[search term] site:snapchat.com | site:facebook.com
```

You could also do the following and get similar results

```
[search term] site:snapchat.com OR site:facebook.com
```

Comment: Yeah, I already found answer here --> [link](https://superuser.com/questions/550026/how-to-search-within-specific-websites-at-once) , but thank you too ! :)